# Delete a visual studio code snippet in macos

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I've just create a snippet in vs code, but I don't find a way to delete it in my operating system (macos ventura).

This is the path where the snippets are stored.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxbzR.png)

But when I tried to get into the "code" folder (as the path in vs code shows), it seems that the folder doesn't exist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Woy.png)

Could anybody tell me how to delete it?

Comment: Have you looked at your $HOME directory ? $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/snippets

Answer (score 0):

1. open setting
2. configure user snipped
3. click on your snipped
4. here you can edit your snipped if not then
5. follow the path where your snipped stored in your local file explorer and then delete it from there

Comment: Hi Devansh Kasaudhan I already did that, the problem is that I can't find the "code" folder... once I get to the Application Support folder (as you can see in the second image I uploaded) I can't find any code folder as the path in vs code shows me.